# Почему CSS в jQuery не работает?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Значит есть два подключенных файла к index.html: jscript.js и style.css;

jscript.js:

```
    var height = window.innerHeight;
var width = window.innerWidth;

var start_point = (width - 790)/2;

    $("#logo").css({
    'left': start_point,
    'top': start_point
});
```

style.css:

```
#logo {
background-color:#3F0;
border:1px dotted #CCCCCC;

width:250px;
height:270px;

position:absolute;

z-index:3;
}
```

index.html:

```
<div id="logo"></div>
```

При этом значения left и top должны находиться в start_point. Но он появляется в верхнем углу. Т.е на него мой jQuery код не действует. Не знаю в чем проблема

**UPDATE**

Думаю проблема в том, что после     'left': start_point нет "px". Как добавить к нему "px"?

что бы ни делал не работает. Дело в самом файле либо, либо в $('#logo').css !!! Надоело уже! Помогите разобраться!

Comment: нет никого???

Comment: Ну так ваша проблема решилась или нет? У всех всё работает, у вас же почему-то не работает или как?

Answer (score 3):

Перенесите jQuery-код ниже вычесления переменной "start_point" — она же еще не объявлена, ничего ей не присвоено, очевидно же.

```
$(function() {
    "use strict";

    var height = window.innerHeight;
    var width = window.innerWidth;

    var start_point = (width - 790)/2;

    $("#logo").css({
        'left': start_point,
        'top': start_point
    });
});
```

"px" добавлять не нужно (нужно только тогда, когда есть "%" или "em" или другие единицы измерения).

Вначале любых скриптов пишите "use strict";, чтобы все ошибки сразу вам выдавались в консоли.

Вообще посмотрите, что такое console.log(start_point) и что там выводится.

Comment: нет, я это понимаю. Тут я неправильно написал код. На самом деле сперва идет вычисление, а потом присвоение. Не сработало все равно. А use strict ничего не вывел

Comment: Это не может не работать — скопипэйстите код на http://jsfiddle.net/ и всё там хорошо. Может быть у вас ширина окна меньше, чем 790 пикселов и поэтому "start_point" получается негативным и блок уходит за пределы экрана?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uUcvJ/ гляньте сами. Только 4-й блок растяните влево, чтобы увидеть другие блоки. Хотя не нужно. Там главная - первая и она находится в верхнем левом углу

Comment: что бы ни делал не работает. Дело в самом файле либо, либо в $('#logo').css !!! Надоело уже! Помогите разобраться!

Comment: Ну так посмотрите в консоль. F12 и вкладка Console — там же все ошибки показаны! В данно случае, у вас в правой части не подключен jQuery из выпадающего меню.

Comment: @navi1893, А чего вы вообще добиться хотите? Продолжите фразу: "*Хочу, чтобы при любом размере окна, блок #logo распологался ...*"