# Почему не работает этот код?

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

```
var elem = $(".elem"), 
elemWidth = elem.width(), 
elemHeight = elem.height(); 
elem.css({ 
    "left":"calc(50% - " + elemWidth/2 + ")", 
    "top":"calc(50% - " + elemHeight /2 + ")" 
});
```

Не делает ничего, должен добавить элементу стили:

```
left:calc(50% - половина своей ширины); 
top:calc(50% - половина своей высоты);
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/218221/256824

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var elem = $(".elem"),
  elemWidth = elem.width(),
  elemHeight = elem.height();
var props = {
  "left": "calc(50% - " + elemWidth / 2 + "px)",
  "top": "calc(50% - " + elemHeight / 2 + "px)"
};
//console.log(props);
elem.css(props);
```

```css
.elem {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: lightgreen;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="elem"></div>
```